# For loop picks only first result from array when output to html table

Tags: php, for-loop, outer-join

Im trying to put out a html table from a database. But this code only picks the first prediction result from every user and writes it all over again in every users column. I really don't know what to change in the code. I've fiddled around with different questions to the database and change the for loop to an foreach loop. Nothing works. Banging my head into the wall now. What to change to make it right? Example of code output here. http://www.fotbolltipset.se/2020/matcher2.php

**Update! Code is rewritten** I've rewritten the code and i'm getting all the data from the database now. But the output still looks weird. What am I doing wrong in the while loops?

```
$matcher = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * ,DATE_FORMAT( gamedate,  '%d %M'  )  AS gamedate FROM matcher LIMIT 0 , 48");
$sql = "SELECT A.namn, enamn, SUM( B.points ) + ( C.points ) AS points
FROM userdata A
LEFT OUTER JOIN matchtips B ON ( A.user_id = B.user_id )
LEFT OUTER JOIN extratips C ON ( A.user_id = C.user_id )
WHERE paid = '1'
GROUP BY A.user_id
ORDER BY enamn, namn";
$games = $conn->query($sql);
$numofrows = mysqli_num_rows($games);
$sql = "SELECT A.namn, enamn, B.*
            FROM userdata A
            LEFT OUTER JOIN matchtips B ON ( A.user_id = B.user_id )
            WHERE paid = '1'
            GROUP BY   matchid,enamn,namn";
$predictions = $conn->query($sql);
print "<div align=center>";
print "<table class=\"kantlinje\" bgcolor=\"#F9F9F9\" border=\"0\" cellpadding=\"4\" cellspacing=\"3\">";
print "<tr><td width=275 colspan=6 class=streck3> <span class=mrubrik>&nbsp;Summa poäng</td>";
$rows = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($games))
    {
    $rows[] = $row;
    $class = ($class == 'raknaodd') ? 'raknaeven' : 'raknaodd';
    print "<td class=$class width=60 align=center colspan=2>";
    print "<span class=mrubrik>";
    print "{$row["points"]}";
    print "</td>";
    }

print "</tr>";
print "<tr><td width=40 align=center> <span class=mrubrik>&nbsp;Datum</td>";
print "<td width=50 align=center> <span class=mrubrik>Grupp</td>";
print '<td width=130> <span class=mrubrik>Match</td>';
print '<td width=70 colspan=3> <span class=mrubrik>Resultat</td>';

foreach($rows as $row)
    {
    $class2 = ($class2 == 'raknaodd') ? 'raknaeven' : 'raknaodd';
    print "<td class=$class2 width=60 colspan=2 align=center>";
    print "{$row["namn"]}<br />{$row["enamn"]}</td>";
    }

print "</tr>";

while ($matchline = mysqli_fetch_assoc($matcher))
    {
    $homegoal = ($matchline['homegoal'] == '') ? null : (int)$matchline['homegoal'];
    $awaygoal = ($matchline['awaygoal'] == '') ? null : (int)$matchline['awaygoal'];
    print "<tr>";
    print "<td width=40>";
    print "<span class=Text4>&nbsp;";
    print ($matchline["gamedate"]);
    print "</td>";
    print "<td width=50 align=center>";
    print "<span class=Text4>";
    print ($matchline["group"]);
    print "</td>";
    print "<td width=130>";
    print "<span class=Text4>{$matchline["hometeam"]}-{$matchline["awayteam"]}</td>";
    print "<td width=30 align=center>";
    print "<span class=Text4>{$matchline["homegoal"]}-{$matchline["awaygoal"]}</td>";
    print "<td width=20 align=center>";
    print "<span class=Text4>{$matchline["sign"]}</td>";
    print "<td width=20>&nbsp;</td>";
    $n = $numofrows;
    $i = 0;
    while ($predictline = mysqli_fetch_assoc($predictions))
        {
        $home_p = $predictline['homescore'];
        $away_p = $predictline['awayscore'];
        $tip = $predictline['sign'];
        if ($i % 2)
            {
            $color12 = 'raknaeven';
            }
          else
            {
            $color12 = 'raknaodd';
            }

        $colors1 = array(
            0 => $color12,
            1 => 'rakna3'
        );
        $colors2 = array(
            0 => $color12,
            1 => 'rakna1'
        );
        $color1 = $color12;
        $color2 = $color12;
        if (!empty($tip) && $homegoal !== null)
            {
            $color1 = $colors1[(int)($home_p == $homegoal && $away_p == $awaygoal) ];
            $color2 = $colors2[(int)(($homegoal == $awaygoal && $tip == 'X') || ($homegoal > $awaygoal && $tip == '1') || ($homegoal < $awaygoal && $tip == '2')) ];
            }

        print "<td width=45 class=$color1 align=center>";
        print "{$home_p}-{$away_p}";
        print "</td>";
        print "<td width=15 class=$color2 align=center>";
        print "{$tip}";
        print "</td>";
        $i++;
        if ($i == $n)
            {
            echo "<tr>";
            $i = 0;
            }
        }
    }

print "</td>";
print "</tr>";
print "</table>";
print "</div>";
```

Comment: Have a look at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ which is probably better for this question.

Comment: At codereview the code must work properly and this doesn't. Not the right place to post it I think.